# Searching for a number in a sorted list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm using Tcl. I have a sorted list of real numbers. Given the number `n` I need to find an index of the list element which is:

- either less of equal to `n`;
- or greater than `n`.

Is there any standard way to do this? `lsearch` expects exact match and can't be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Tcl 8.6 (still in beta) lsearch will do what your asking, the `-sorted` and new `-bisect` options allow the following:

> `-bisect`
>   Inexact search when the list elements are in sorted order. For an increasing list the last index where the element is less than
>   or equal to the pattern is returned. For a decreasing list the last
>   index where the element is greater than or equal to the pattern is
>   returned.

For Tcl versions prior to 8.6 your going to have to roll your own code, given that the list is sorted it should be fairly straightforward to write a binary search with the properties that you require, Rosetta code [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Binary_search) contains a description of a pure binary search and also a Tcl implemention.  You should be able to use this as your starting point.

Here is a very quick version I created, it returns the index of either the value you search for or the value greater than it.  The exception to watch for is the end of the list, searching for a value beyond the largest element returns the largest element.  It's only had minimal testing so if you do use it do some additional tests!  I also don't stop if the search finds the value, if this is likely to happen often you may want to optimize for this.

```
set lst [lsort -real [list 1.2 3.4 5.4 7.9 2.3 1.1 0.9 22.7 4.3]]
puts $lst

# Assumes that lst is sorted in ascending order
proc bisect { lst val } {

    puts "Looking for $val in $lst"

    set len [llength $lst]

    # Initial interval - the start to the middle of the list
    set start 0
    set end [expr $len - 1]
    set mid [expr $len / 2]
    set lastmid -1

    while { $mid != $lastmid } {
        if { [expr $val <= [lindex $lst $mid]] } {
            # val lies somewhere between the start and the mid
            set end $mid

        } else {
            # val lies somewhere between mid and end
            set start [expr $mid + 1]
        }

        set lastmid $mid
        set mid [expr ($start + $end ) / 2]
    }

    return $mid
}

set res [bisect $lst 2.4]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"

set res [bisect $lst -1]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"

set res [bisect $lst 999]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"

set res [bisect $lst 1.2]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"

set res [bisect $lst 0.9]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"

set res [bisect $lst 22.7]
puts "found [lindex $lst $res] at index $res"
```